# Node plus MongoDb build and execute query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using nodejs and mongodb.  I'm trying to build a query and execute it so that I can return a json object through this api.  When I do the following I get the error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'exec' of undefined`

How should I be setting this up differently.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var db = new mongodb.Db('MyDD', new mongodb.Server('localhost', 27017, {}));

exports.findAll = function(req, res) {

  const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit);

    let query = GetTransactionList(limit)

    query.exec(function(err,items){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.json(items);
        }
    })
}

function GetTransactionList(limit){

    console.log("GetTransactionList entered with limit: ", limit)

    let query;

    if (limit){
        query =  db.collection('transtest').find({},{limit:limit}).sort({postdate: -1})
    } else {
         query =  db.collection('transtest').find()
    }

    return query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should first import or create `GetTransactionList` scheme.
but in your example it is not a scheme and does not implement method exec.
its a plain function.

Comment: Are schemas available for MongoDB?  I thought that was if you are using Mongoose.  I don't want to use Mongoose.

Comment: you don't have exec by default in mongo. you should check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/
or again use `then`

Answer (score 0):

Because the find() method returns a [cursor](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html), you may want to append the **[`toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray)** method of the cursor to return a Promise instead when no callback is passed.

Consider rewriting your code as follows:

```
exports.findAll = function(req, res) {
    const query = GetTransactionList(parseInt(req.query.limit));
    query.then(res.json).catch(console.log);
    /* Above is equivalent to
    query.then(function(items) {
        res.json(items);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    */
}

function GetTransactionList(limit){
    console.log("GetTransactionList entered with limit: ", limit);
    const cursor = db.collection('transtest').find({});
    return limit ? cursor.sort([['postdate', -1]]).limit(limit).toArray() : cursor.toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exec is a helper method of Mongoose defined in **mongoose** not in **mongodb**, so in mongodb the `find()` method return a cursor to the selected documents and you can use `toArray()` method to returns an array of the documents from the cursor.

Simple Example

```
db.collection('restaurants').find().toArray(function(err, documents){

documents.forEach(function(doc){
        console.log(doc.name);
});

});
```

In your case

```
query.toArray(function(err, items){
    //assert.equal(err, null);
   items.forEach(function(item){
       console.log(item);
   });
   res.json(items);
})
```

I hope this could help you